# Москва — столица?

Tags: синонимы

В последнее время столицами стали центры субъектов страны (прежние областные города).

В Малом академическом словаре без пометки «перен.» или «ирон.» во II знач. указывается: «Какой-л. город, село, являющиеся центром чего-л. (области, края и т. п.)». И т. п.! Характерны примеры: «...невзрачна столица дальнего, серого земледельческого уезда» из Короленко; «...не обычный город, а столица степного края» от Бабаевского.

Если столиц становится много (включая неформальные, сто и более), то как теперь быть с главным городом?

Comment: "Столица" происходит от "стольный", которое, в свою очередь, связано со словом "престол".  Каждое княжество на Руси имело свою столицу, где находился престол правящего князя. Затем так стал называться  главный город объединенного русского государства, где находился  престол царя.  После переноса столицы в Санкт-Петербург Москву стали называть "первопрестольной". Не надо забывать также, что  превращение Москвы в столицу Руси  было связано с переносом в нее  престола Киевского митрополита Петра (13 век). Выражения типа "столица региона" носят переносный характер и не имеют  юридического смысла.

Comment: Во-первых, Москва не превратилась в столицу, а стала. Во-вторых, вопрос несколько в другом (утрируя): Москва — столица Московской области?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы имеете в виду Малый академический словарь Евгеньевой А. П. 1957—1984гг,то там как раз такая помета есть:значок || означает "переносное", и примеры соответствующие, где столица - центр чего-то:  невзрачная столица  серого земледельческого уезда,столица степного края. Так что столиц не становится много, в каждом государстве одна.

Энциклопедический словарь экономики и права(2005) объясняет:
СТОЛИЦА - главный город, административно-политический центр государства. С. обычно является местопребыванием центральных (общенациональных) правительственных, парламентских и судебных учреждений. Как правило, С. выделяется в самостоятельную административную единицу с особым режимом управления. В большинстве федеративных государств С. находится на территории специального федерального округа, не входящего в состав ни одного из субъектов федерации и, как правило, не являющегося самостоятельным субъектом федерации. В большинстве стран местопребывание С. указано непосредственно в тексте конституции. В соответствии с п. 2 ст. 70 Конституции РФ 1993 г столицей РФ является город Москва. Статус столицы устанавливается федеральным законом. При этом, однако, Москва является самостоятельным субъектом Российской Федерации.
http://endic.ru/ecolaw/Stolica-5350.html

Итак,Москва - столица Российской Федерации, город федерального значения, административный центр Центрального федерального округа и центр Московской области, в состав которой не входит.

Никак не столица Московской области, она даже не входит в неё. В Москве одна зарплата, в Московской области другая - как у всех остальных областей, без доплат.

Comment: Никак не столица Московской области? И в переносном смысле?

Comment: Что-то в переносном смысле не встречала такое выражение. Какой сюда смысл можно вложить? Что самое лучшее место в области? Не относится она к области, это столица государства, центр округа, но не столица  области.

Comment: Да, но мы не знаем другого города, который является столицей столичной области. В переносном смысле, разумеется.

Comment: Административный центр Московской области не определён, фактически — город Москва, часть органов государственной власти расположена в Красногорске.Дом Правительства Московской области — комплекс правительственных зданий Московской области в Мякининской пойме на берегу Москвы-реки, на территории города Красногорска, возле 65-66 км МКАД, недалеко от торгового центра Крокус-Сити (на территории последнего находится станция метро«Мякинино»).В нём находится большинство областных органов власти и в том числе одно из служебных помещений Губернатора Московской области.

Comment: Понял. Фактически Москва — областная столица. Так я о том же. Сайтов, где есть списки областей с областными городами РФ — столицами регионов — множество, и совсем не в переносном смысле. Например: http://oblasti.narod.ru/